# Drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire E1 510?

Tags: command-line, drivers, laptop, acer

I recently made the decision to change to Ubuntu on my E1 510 laptop for security reasons. I simply did not want to let Microsoft read everything I type. And it is a fantastic choice. It runs off the shelves (so to say) all functions I needed until now included. I changed the HDD for an SSD and made the OS change then, too.

Now, it looks as if Acer does not supply with Linux drivers. I went to acer.com searched for drivers, entered my SNID and the only drivers they offered were for windows 8.1!

So right now the Ubuntu updates every other day, also including OS enhancements (that's what it says, anyways.

Now, can I download the specific drivers manually or do I have to do it via command line? **If with Ubuntu the drivers can be installed, how to do it?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install 16.04.2 so you get kernel 4.8.  If the SSD is a second drive and this is not a fresh install (e.g. initially installed 16.04 or 16.04.1), you will need to run the following command for hardware improvements:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

To be sure, confirm 4.8 kernel with:

```
uname -r
```

Just in case its a different issue, make sure drive mode in the BIOS is set to "AHCI" instead of "RAID".  Also disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot.

Comment: Thank you! the kernel was 4.4 and is now updated. also the BIOS settings are adjusted. Is there anything else to do when a fresh install is made, besides ufw enable? Im just getting started and am happy to have figured aliases by now :)

Thank you!